# Confusion with weird redirect parameter in django comments (default application)

Tags: python, django, url, get

I was just curious about a weird property in django comments. When after a comment post occurs (at /comments/post/) there will be a redirect by django to, ?c="comment_pk". From django's comments lib:

```
"""
Handle the "where should I go next?" part of comment views.

The next value could be a kwarg to the function (``default``), or a
``?next=...`` GET arg, or the URL of a given view (``default_view``). See
the view modules for examples.

Returns an ``HttpResponseRedirect``.
"""
next = data.get("next", default)
if next is None:
    next = urlresolvers.reverse(default_view)
if get_kwargs:
    if '#' in next:
        tmp = next.rsplit('#', 1)
        next = tmp[0]
        anchor = '#' + tmp[1]
    else:
        anchor = ''

    joiner = ('?' in next) and '&' or '?'
    next += joiner + urllib.urlencode(get_kwargs) + anchor
return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

I was just curious why the makers of django decided to have this. What's wrong with just redirecting back to the same page? Is the comment pk argument really needed for anything? For my view it isn't.

Also when I tried to modify the httpresponse to a value of '' empty string, it wouldn't let me due to some **init** expects 2 parameters error. If this ?c=pk really isn't needed, how can I get rid of this automatic redirect parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Having the comment pk would allow you to scroll to the new comment, among other things. (Not that there aren't other ways to do that-- I'm just saying, that might be what they originally had in mind.)

Comment: Ahh, didn't think of that at all, thanks! But still, wouldn't it have been better for them to leave that part to us? Was it really necessary for the redirect value?

Comment: Certainly it would be good for that to be documented, if nothing else! I don't know much about the comments app though, to be completely honest.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the comments framework to have a facebook style comments and it redirects to the same page, snippet below. Notice the way to redirect the form to the same page:

`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/your/redirect/url"/>`

```
{% get_comment_form for update as form %}

                                    <div class="commentForm">

                                      <form action="/comments/post/" method="post">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                         <textarea class="commentBox" id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea>


                                        <input id="id_name" type="hidden" name="name" value="{{user.username}}" maxlength="50"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" id="id_email" value="{{user.email}}"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="url" id="id_url" value=""/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="id_honeypot" value=""/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/your/redirect/url/"/>

                                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                              {{hidden}}
                                            {% endfor %}

                                        <button class="btn comment-btn" type="submit" name="submit"> Comment</button>


                                    </form>
```